# Postgres: Count Rows with a Left Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do some analytics using Postgres, where I do have 2 tables, called: `predictionstate` and `pageviews`.

**The `predictionstate` table:**

This table contains the columns with our algorithm outcomes, using the following structure:

- id (`{company_identifier}:{user_identifier}`)
- model (reference string value)
- prediction (float number between 0.0 and 1.0)

**The `pageviews` table:**

This table contains user information, using the following structure:

- company_identifier
- user_identifier
- pageview_current_url_type

**Question**

I'm trying to get the data based on our best model, to analyze how accurate it is, where basically I need to know to create the Segments and count how many members I do have on it. The following code does that:

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    myrange::text || '-' || (myrange + 0.1)::text AS segment,
    myrange as r_min, myrange + 0.1 as r_max
  FROM generate_series(0.0, 0.9, 0.1) AS myrange
)
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 1) as company_identifier,
  p.model,
  r.segment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 2))) as "segment_users"
FROM
  ranges r
INNER JOIN predictionstate p ON p.prediction BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max
GROUP BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment
ORDER BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment;
```

But the issue that I have, since I don't know exactly how to do it, it's that for each (company, model, segment), and need to get the data of how accurate it is, querying the `pageviews` table and identifying the `pageview_current_url_type == 'BUYSUCCESS'`.

What I tried, but didn't work:

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    myrange::text || '-' || (myrange + 0.1)::text AS segment,
    myrange as r_min, myrange + 0.1 as r_max
  FROM generate_series(0.0, 0.9, 0.1) AS myrange
)
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 1) as company_identifier,
  p.model,
  r.segment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 2))) as "segment_users",
  b.n as "converted_users"
FROM
  ranges r,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(pvs.user_identifier)) as n
    FROM pageviews pvs
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            SPLIT_PART(id, ':', 1) as company_identifier,
            SPLIT_PART(id, ':', 2) as user_identifier
        FROM predictionstate ps
        WHERE prediction BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max ) users
        ON (
            pvs.user_identifier = users.user_identifier AND
            pvs.company_identifier= users.company_identifier) 
        WHERE pageview_current_url_type = 'BUYSUCCESS'

  ) b
INNER JOIN predictionstate p ON p.prediction BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max
GROUP BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment
ORDER BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment;
```

TL;DR: I need to count a JOIN based on the main query users.

**EDIT:**

I added an SQL Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5sQiZD6mHwdnwvVfvL9MAh/0 .

What I want to know, for those `segment_users`, how many of them have a `pageview_current_url_type = 'BUYSUCCESS'`, addind one more column to the result: `segmented_really_bought`.

**EDIT 2: One more attempt not working (ERROR:  column "p.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)**

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    myrange::text || '-' || (myrange + 0.1)::text AS segment,
    myrange as r_min, myrange + 0.1 as r_max
  FROM generate_series(0.0, 0.9, 0.1) AS myrange
)
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 1) as company_identifier,
  p.model,
  r.segment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(SPLIT_PART(p.id, ':', 2))) as "segment_users",
  COUNT(b.*) as "converted_users"
FROM
  ranges r
INNER JOIN predictionstate p ON p.prediction BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT users.company_identifier, COUNT(users.user_identifier) AS n
  FROM pageviews
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SPLIT_PART(ps.id, ':', 2) AS user_identifier,
           SPLIT_PART(ps.id, ':', 1) AS company_identifier
    FROM predictionstate ps
    WHERE provider_id=47 AND
          prediction > 0.7
   ) users ON (
      pageviews.user_identifier=users.user_identifier AND
      pageviews.company_identifier=users.company_identifier
    )
  WHERE pageview_current_url_type='BUYSUCCESS'
  GROUP BY users.company_identifier
) AS b
ON (
  b.company_identifier = company_identifier
)
GROUP BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment
ORDER BY company_identifier, p.model, r.segment;
```

**EDIT 3: Added the desired output**

Generated using this code: https://gist.github.com/brunoalano/479265b934a67dc02092fb54a846fe1e

```
company, model, segment, segment_users, really_bought
company_a, model_a, 0.3-0.4, 1, 3
company_a, model_a, 0.5-0.6, 1, 1
company_a, model_b, 0.2-0.3, 1, 3
company_a, model_c, 0.2-0.3, 1, 1
company_a, model_c, 0.7-0.8, 1, 3
company_b, model_a, 0.3-0.4, 3, 2
company_b, model_b, 0.5-0.6, 2, 1
company_b, model_b, 0.6-0.7, 1, 1
company_b, model_c, 0.5-0.6, 1, 0
company_b, model_c, 0.8-0.9, 1, 1
```

Comment: 1. Why is your ID a concatenated string? It would be much easier in your code if you would have two columns as primary key. 2. This seems quiet complex. Could you please add a sample table and expected output?

Comment: @S-Man I created it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5sQiZD6mHwdnwvVfvL9MAh/0

Comment: What's your expected result for the sample you've posted? Add it to your question please.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski I added the desired output and the code that I used to generate it. Sorry for that.

Comment: My answer seems to be what you're looking for, though I don't know why there are less segments in your output than the data generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without sample output what you need, but I think what you're looking for is:

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    myrange::text || '-' || (myrange + 0.1)::text AS segment,
    myrange as r_min, myrange + 0.1 as r_max
  FROM generate_series(0.0, 0.9, 0.1) AS myrange
)
SELECT
  p.company_identifier,
  p.model,
  r.segment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(p.user_identifier)) as "segment_users",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN pv.pageview_current_url_type = 'BUYSUCCESS' THEN 1 END) AS segmented_really_bought
FROM
  ranges r
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(id, ':', 1) as company_identifier,
    SPLIT_PART(id, ':', 2) as user_identifier,
    model,
    prediction
  FROM
    predictionstate
  ) p ON p.prediction BETWEEN r.r_min AND r.r_max
LEFT JOIN pageviews pv ON 
  p.company_identifier = pv.company_identifier
  AND p.user_identifier = pv.user_identifier
GROUP BY p.company_identifier, p.model, r.segment
ORDER BY p.company_identifier, p.model, r.segment;
```

Changes to your fiddle query:

- replaced `predictionstate` with a subquery that we join to, where we do the `split_part` logic to get comapny and user identifiers as separate columns
- used those identifiers to `LEFT JOIN` to `pageviews`
- added `segmented_really_bought` column with a CASEd `COUNT`

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1e41819e7a2fbf47d229b14131761a05)

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    myrange::text || '-' || (myrange + 0.1)::text AS segment,
    myrange as r_min, myrange + 0.1 as r_max
  FROM generate_series(0.0, 0.9, 0.1) AS myrange
), pstate AS (                                         -- A
  SELECT 
    SPLIT_PART(ps.id, ':', 1) AS company_identifier,
    SPLIT_PART(ps.id, ':', 2) AS user_identifier,
    model,
    prediction
  FROM predictionstate ps
)
SELECT 
  company_identifier, model, segment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_identifier) as segment_users,    -- B
  -- C: 
  COUNT(user_identifier) FILTER (WHERE pageview_current_url_type = 'BUYSUCCESS') as really_bought
FROM pstate ps
LEFT JOIN ranges r 
ON prediction BETWEEN r_min AND r_max
LEFT JOIN pageviews pv 
USING (company_identifier, user_identifier)
GROUP BY company_identifier, model, segment
ORDER BY company_identifier, model, segment
```

A: I would really recommend that your id column should be split into two columns for better handling. This would save you much time on splitting the string (on writing queries and execute them) and it's more readable. That's why I added the second CTE.

B: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` counts the distinct users in the group

C: counts all users (not distinct) but filters out the expected status before counting.

---

I was wondering: What if a prediction is exactly on a threshold, for example `0.3`. With the `BETWEEN` clause this range would be joined both in range `0.2-0.3` and range `0.3-0.4` (because `BETWEEN` equals `r_min >= x >= r_max`). It would be better to define the ranges as `r_min >= x > r_max` or `r_min > x >= r_max`. I made the join as you mentioned in your example but I would prefer to change it. I still don't know in which direction